# Search Function returns wrong results

Tags: c++11

I have made a function for my program that reads from a text file, adds content to a vector and then search in that vector. The Problem is that even if the file is empty it shows that it found something, on the other side if i change return value to 0 it does not give results at all!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

 using namespace std;

 vector<string> contacts;


 //This function returns at what index the name is found
  int searchContact(string contactToSearch) 
  {


   string entry;
   ifstream input;
   input.open("contacts.txt");

     while (input.good()) 
         {
             while (getline(input, entry))
                 {
                     contacts.push_back(entry);

                 }
             input.close();
         }

   for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) 
     {

         if(contactToSearch == contacts[i]) 
             {
         //Found => Returning index rest of program can see index
         return i;
            }
      }

      return 1;
     }
```

Comment: In the loop where you read the contents of the file, the outer loop is not needed.

Comment: By the way, how do you differ between the item you search for not being found (when you return `1` after the loop), and when the item you searched for was found at index `1`? You should probably return something like `-1` if the item was not found.

Comment: Also note that when you compare strings using `==`, it's an *exact* comparison, and is case sensitive.

Comment: If i change return to -1 i get that my result was found at -1 index.

Comment: And that means what you searched for wasn't found, you need to actually *check* for that possibility in the calling function. Also, re-read my last comment.

Comment: Please show us an example of input, like what's in the file and what you search for.

Comment: Current contacts in list: 
0) Dimitrios,Sundsvall,0760150660,Single,dimi@mail.com,07/09/1986
1) Emil,Sundsvall,0701245789,Married,emil@email.com,01/02/1995
>3
Contact to search for: Emil
Emil not found in database.

Comment: If you have a long line with multiple fields in it (like a [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which you seem to have), then your comparison of e.g. `"Emil"` to the whole line will *never* be true. What you probably need to do is to learn how to use *structures* and then split each record (line) into its fields and initialize the structure with those values, then have a collection of those structures. Then you can check the first-name field of the structure to find a match.

Comment: Also note that you can't have `0` meaning "nothing found", as `0` is a valid index in the vector. `-1` is probably the best bet.

Comment: The issue is that we are not allowed to use structures.

Comment: Then you need to get the sub-string of the data from the file, from the beginning to the first comma (but not including the comma), and compare only that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just refactored your code a little. Further improvements are possible, but to begin with

1) You dont need a while for input.good()

2) You were trying to return 0 and 1 which are indeed valid positions where the string could have been present in the vector

All these aside, I still think your code might not properly populated the array  The reasons for this maybe :- case sensitive comparison, reading incorrect file, binary file.. etc..

Here is a refactored code that you could use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void readContacts(const string &fileName inputFileName, vector<string> &contacts){
    string entry;
    ifstream input;
    input.open(inputFileName);
    if (input.good())
    {
        while (getline(input, entry))
            contacts.push_back(entry);
        input.close();
    }
}

int searchContact(const string &contactToSearch, vector<string> &contacts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contactToSearch == contacts[i])
            return i;       
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    vector<string> contacts;
    // This needs to be filled in with the contact name u want to search
    string contactToSearch;
    readContacts("contacts.txt", contacts);
    int index = searchContact(contactToSearch, contacts)
        if (index != -1)
            cout << "Found Contact " << contactToSearch" at location " << index << endl;
        else
            cout << "Could Not find contact " << contactToSearch << endl;
}
```